# GCP Label Regex - re2 - to Count occurrence of a word

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, label, re2

Would appreciate if someone could assist if there's a way to "count" number of occurrences of a specific word in GCP Labels - does something like `re2_count()` works? if so can you share an example on how would it work?

Comment: May we know how do you capture, are you using Cloud Logging, Phyton, JS etc? Can you also share what did you do so far or any error messages. This [Label](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels#default_labels) doc might able help you.

Comment: Thanks! was able to achieve this by applying a count on another label that had unique value. As it appears by default GCP Labels pick distant count instead of count.